# prevent dot in a text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a quantity text box which should not allow negative sign, and  '.' 
 character.

I have tried a jquery block but it allow '.'. I want to block '.' in a text box

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#used_quantity').keypress(function(event) {
  if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="used_quantity">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do with `keydown` event.Only match with key value, not with string of the input

**`Updated`**

with backspace

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#used_quantity').keydown(function(event) {
    if ((event.which != 46) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57) && (event.which != 8)) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="used_quantity">
```

Comment: This also makes it so you don't have backspace, is that also what he wants?

Comment: see my updated answer. backspace escaping from preventing

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the condition to `event.which == 46 || event.which == 45` to ignore the `.` and the `-` respectively.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#used_quantity').keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 46 || event.which == 45 || event.which < 48 || event.which > 57) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="used_quantity">
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check this code. It will work. Remove

```
if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && 
(event.which < 48 || event.which > 57))
```

condition to

```
if ((event.which < 48 || event.which > 57) && event.which != 45) {
```

Check jsliddle **[EXAMPLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/kitcodes/6zqfuyqd/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Change the condition as `(((event.which == 46 || event.which == 45 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1)) || (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57))`. on `keypress` event

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#used_quantity').keypress(function(event) {
  
    if (((event.which == 46 || event.which == 45 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1)) || (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="used_quantity">
```

Comment: this allowing character

Comment: Sorry i didn't noticed that now i have edited my condition as `(((event.which == 46 || event.which == 45 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1)) || (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57))` Now it's works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('#used_quantity').bind("change  input", function () {
    var value = $(this).val().replace(/([^0-9].*)/g, "");
    $(this).val(value);
})
```